Automatically Pull from Main Branch of GitHub on Mac
I'm developing an IOS App using React Native.
My problem:
I have a Windows PC where I'm doing a majority of the code and a Mac Laptop running the iPhone Emulator.
I push to GitHub on my Windows PC and manually fetch + pull on my Mac, it updates the view of my emulator.
I want to set up some way for my Mac to automatically fetch + pull when new code comes into the main branch to save me the time of manually fetching and pulling. Is this possible?
I saw a few other similar questions but I didn't find anything useful for Mac.

git pull incorporates git fetch - but if you want to automate this then you'll need to use a webhook (not a Git hook) to trigger the Mac to pull, and that'll require an endpoint that GitHub can access, which may cause security concerns.

As a side note: pull = fetch + merge (literally this is what happens).

VS Code can assist you with this.
From https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview:

VS Code is able to periodically fetch changes from your remotes. This enables VS Code to show how many changes your local repository is ahead or behind the remote. This feature is disabled by default and you can use the git.autofetch setting to enable it.

From https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings:
// When set to true, commits will automatically be fetched from the default remote of the current Git repository. Setting to `all` will fetch from all remotes.
"git.autofetch": false,

// Duration in seconds between each automatic git fetch, when `git.autofetch` is enabled.
"git.autofetchPeriod": 180,

